# Best practices when using a database and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to determine the correct way to establish a DB connection within a process.map() function. Do I establish the connection and close it within the function thats being run? Do I do this outside of the process.map()? Below is my some psuedo code thats close to what I currently have.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
import pyodbc
server = DB_SERVER
database = DATABASE
username = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD 
 
def ref_worker(file):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    temp_data = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str) 
     
    # logic here

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_string = "insert into db (column) values(field)
    cursor.execute(sql_string, temp_data)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = ''
    driver_names = [x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.endswith(' for SQL Server')]
    if driver_names:
        driver = driver_names[0]
    if driver:
        conn_str = 'DRIVER={}; ...'.format(driver)
    else:
        print('(No suitable driver found. Cannot connect.)')

     file_list = pd.read_csv('list_of_files.csv', header=None, dtype=str)
     pool = Pool(8)  # Create a multiprocessing Pool
     pool.map(ref_worker, file_list)  # process data_inputs iterable with pool
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

Comment: A database connection does not work across processes. You either do everything inside a worker function or everything outside.

Comment: @KlausD. so the code I have above is correct for having it inside the worker function? Or do I need to put the driver & conn_str in there as well?